# Retriving nodes by content type using Drupal::entityQuery

Tags: nodes, database, 8, entities

I created a content type named `product`. How can I retrive all node of such content type using the [`entityQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8) method?

I tried with this, but it doesn't works:

```
$ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('product')
  ->execute();

$products = \Drupal::entityManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadMultiple($ids);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we do this:

```
$ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'product')
  ->execute();

$products = \Drupal::entityManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadMultiple($ids);
```